# Using SecurityServiceProvider results in fatal error

Tags: doctrine, silex

I followed the [tutorial](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html) on Silex's website in order to implement HTTP authentication.

But it results in this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseEvent::isMasterRequest() in /home/auke/projects/nelleketekent/nelleketekent/vendor/symfony/security/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php on line 53
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Looks like your dependencies are out-of-sync, `isMasterRequest()` was added nearly month ago to both `HttpKernel` and `Security` components. Please try tunning `composer update`

Comment: Ty, had to edit my version numbers in composer.json. Please provider your comment as an answer and I'll mark your answer as correct.